# Switched to Wicd instead of network manager but intel 7260ac card is only showing abgn speeds

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless, wicd

I switched to Wicd due to the bugs with network manager and my intel wireless 7260ac card but wicd only shows abgn speeds how can I get the AC speed back?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD

Also I know I can turn off wifi power management by typing **sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off** How can I have wifi power management turned off after rebooting?

I know if I use Network-Manager I can follow the following steps below to turn it off but I'm using Wicd what are the steps to turn off wifi power management in Wicd?

```
Go to directory

/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/

and open the file

default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

By default it is wifi.powersave = 3 so just change it to wifi.powersave = 2.
```

I also did a **uname -a**

```
Linux sys76 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also did a **lsb_release -a**

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I type the command **sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:4e:64:8e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-62-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
       logical name: enp4s0f2
       version: 0a
       serial: 00:90:f5:f9:d9:f8
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

I do a **iwconfig wlp3s0**

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"5ghz"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.805 GHz  Access Point: E0:3F:49:93:3F:14   
          Bit Rate=292.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:64   Missed beacon:0
```

I did a **dmesg | grep 7260**

```
[    4.559524] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
```

I also did a **ls /lib/firmware | grep 7260**

```
iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
```

here's the **dmesg | grep iwlwifi**

```
[    4.523257] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.559524] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    4.559574] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.559799] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    4.945647] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.974844] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    5.975069] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.181952] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.182177] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   89.160588] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   89.160815] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   89.366627] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   89.366853] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   89.617083] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   89.617308] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   89.830324] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   89.830550] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
```

Comment: I do not see any problems. The link speed depends on router settings and conditions.

Comment: @Pilot6 when I used network-manger I was getting 588Mb/s for Bit Rate now Bit Rate is around 300Mb/s . Also I know I can turn off wifi power management by typing `sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off` How can I have wifi power management turned off using Wicd after rebooting?

Comment: Network Manager or wicd do not affect performance or link speed. You are doing wrong things.

Comment: @Pilot6 ok, How can I have wifi power management turned off using Wicd after I reboot?  I updated the question